# How to create Observable for async response?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have one async-method, like this:

```
void getPlaceInfo(Place place, PlaceCallback callback)
```

For example my `PlaceCallback` has one method:

```
void success(InfoPlace place);
```

I want create `Observable` for waiting response from two requests:

```
getPlaceInfo(...); // first call
getPlaceInfo(...); // second call
```

And then I want to get both response at the same time.

Can I make it?

Comment: Did you tried with Singleton class which will be observable and set a list of subscribers on that singleton and just notify when the first & the second call finishes. If you need some code snippets i can write for you

Answer (score 2):

So you need to combine 2 callbacks to evaluate a function like:

```java
Response computeResponse(InfoPlace infoPlace, InfoPlace infoPlace2) {
    ...
}
```

And you want to use Rx for this. There is two problem here; wrapping the callback method into Observable, and combine them.

You can't just instantiate an Observable and call myObservable.send(value) or myObservable.next(value). The first solution is to use a [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html). Another solution (the one below) is to create the observable with Observable.create(). You call the callback method and create the listener inside the method Observable.create(), because it's inside Observable.create() that you can call onSuccess() method, the method who told the Observable to pass down a value:

```java
Single<InfoPlace> getInfoPlaceSingle(Place place) {
    return Single.create(e -> getPlaceInfo(place, new PlaceCallback() {
        @Override
        public void success(InfoPlace infoPlace) {
            e.onSuccess(infoPlace);
        }
    }));
}
```

Or with Java 8:

```java
Single<InfoPlace> getInfoPlaceSingle(Place place) {
    return Single.create(e -> getPlaceInfo(place, e::onSuccess));
}
```

Note, I used [Single](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html) over Observable, since you await only one value. The interest is a more expressive contract for your function.

Wrapping things into Observable is a pain, but now you are in the reactive realm where Rx provide you a complete toolbox to deal with them. The second part - combining the observables - is easy:

```java
Single.zip(getInfoPlaceSingle(place1), getInfoPlaceSingle(place2), this::computeResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your async calls using `Observable.fromEmitter()` and you can then use `Observable.zip()` to combine the calls.

Comment: another, slightly less clean approach, is to wrap in `Observable.create()`